# MySQL query to determine records that are related to category A and B

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is a simplified version of my data:

```
products:
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Product X |
|  2 | Product Y |
|  3 | Product Z |
+----+-----------+

categories:
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Hotel         |
|  2 | Accommodation |
+----+---------------+

category_product
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | product_id | category_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 |           1 |
|  2 |          1 |           2 |
|  3 |          2 |           1 |
|  4 |          3 |           2 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

How do I construct an efficient query that will only retrieve `products` that have **both** categories "Hotel" and "Accommodation" related (eg. Product X)?

I first tried a join approach

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products p
JOIN category_product cp
ON p.id = cp.product_id
WHERE cp.category_id = 1 OR cp.category_id = 2
```

^ This doesn't work because it doesn't contrain the query to **containing both**.

I have found an approach using sub-queries that works... but I've been warned against sub-queries for performance reasons:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products p
WHERE
(
    SELECT id
    FROM category_product
    WHERE product_id = p.id
    AND category_id = 1
)
AND
(
    SELECT id
    FROM category_product
    WHERE product_id = p.id
    AND category_id = 2
)
```

Are there any better solutions (or how about alternatives)? I've considered de-normalizing categories to an extra column on products but would ideally like to avoid that. Hoping for a magic bullet solution!

**UPDATE**

I've run some of the (great) solutions provided in the answers:
My data is 235 000 category_product rows and 58 000 products and obviously benchmarks are always dependent on environment and indexes etc.

"Relational division" @podiluska

```
2 categories: 2826 rows  ~ 20ms 
5 categories: 46 rows ~ 25-30 ms 
8 categories: 1 rows ~ 25-30 ms
```

"Where exists" @Tim Schmelter

```
2 categories: 2826 rows  ~ 5-7ms 
5 categories: 46 rows ~ 30 ms 
8 categories: 1 rows ~ 300 ms
```

One can see the results start to diverge with having a greater number of categories thrown in. I'll look at using "relational division" as it provides consistent results but implementation might cause me to look at "where exists" too  (long format http://pastebin.com/6NRX0QbJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
     inner join 
(
    select product_ID
    from category_product
    where category_id in (1,2)
    group by product_id
    having count(distinct category_id)=2
) pc
    on p.id = pc.product_id
```

This technique is called "relational division"

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from products p
where
    (
        select
            count(distinct cp.category_id)
        from category_product as cp
        where
            cp.product_id = p.id and
            cp.category_id in (1, 2)
    ) = 2
```

or you can use exists

```
select *
from products p
where
    exists
    (
        select
            count(distinct cp.category_id)
        from category_product as cp
        where
            cp.product_id = p.id and
            cp.category_id in (1, 2)
        having count(distinct cp.category_id) = 2
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roman. I tried your first query but it took _forever_ to return a result. Maybe it's because I'm on InnoDB (I've read using `count()` is not as fast on InnoDB. I've gone to looking at the other solutions which seem more performant.

Comment: Yes, i think `inner join` with grouped table will be better solution

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT P.* FROM Products P
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM category_product cp
    WHERE cp.product_id = p.id
    AND category_id = 1
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM category_product cp
    WHERE cp.product_id = p.id
    AND category_id = 2
)
```

Comment: It's not reusable at all. What if you need to check if product not in two categiores, but in 10? in 100?

Comment: @RomanPekar: But that's a different requirement. `EXISTS` is just the best and most efficient for this.

Comment: well it make sense. Then, I'll try to find more beautiful syntax for that :)

Comment: Unless you create indexes specifically to optimise this query, my experiments (admittedly on SQL server) show that relational division is faster than exists in most cases

Comment: @podiluska: I presume proper indices(only pks and fks are involved), all the more on sql-server. I often use such queries like above on tables with more than 50M records. They're really efficient.

Comment: By indexes, I meant indexes specifically tuned for this query - using just plain indexes on category and product, relational division was still faster.

Comment: Two downvotes, would somebody care to explain? OP himself has measured that this approach is the most effcient for his requirement, it's also the most readable, adaptable and easiest.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT categories.name,products.name 
FROM 
category_product,category,product 
where 
    category_product.product_id=product.id 
and 
   category_product.category_id=category.id 
    and 
   (
      select count(1) from category_product 
      where 
      category_product.categoty_id=1
      or 
      category_product.categoty_id=2 
     group by product_id having count(1)=2
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
JOIN category_product cp
ON p.id = cp.product_id
WHERE cp.category_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cp.category_id) = 2
```

Comment: it's better to write count(distinct category_id) = 2. It will work in more cases, for example, for more than 2 categories. And for tables where `product_id, category_id` is not unique combination

Comment: I have updated by answer. Although the original would work fine providing there are no duplicates, which there are not in his example and I see no reason for there to be, other than a flawed system.